# Matching word boundries with non alnums included

Tags: python, regex

Example sentence...

```
words = "7 day f/u  with customer's."
```

I want to store the index of the first character of each word in a list. This almost works...

```
>>> [match.start() for match in re.finditer(r"\b\w", words)]
[0, 2, 6, 8, 11, 16, 25]
```

However I want non-alphanumeric characters adjacent or within words to be counted as part of the adjacent or enclosing word. The characters at indexes 8 and 25 are not necessarily new words. Some detail on the regex i used...

'\b' : Matches the empty string, but only at the beginning or end of a word.

'\w' : When the LOCALE and UNICODE flags are not specified, matches any alphanumeric character and the underscore; this is equivalent to the set [a-zA-Z0-9_].

https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html

Taking what is said about '\w' I got the same results this...

```
>>> [match.start() for match in re.finditer(r"\b[a-zA-Z0-9_]", words)]
[0, 2, 6, 8, 11, 16, 25]
```

Adding a forward slash inside the brackets does not give what is expected to me.

```
>>> [match.start() for match in re.finditer(r"\b[a-zA-Z0-9_/]", words)]
[0, 2, 6, 7, 8, 11, 16, 24, 25]
```

Desired output is...
    [0, 2, 6, 11, 16]

Comment: Try `\b[a-zA-Z0-9_\/]`

Comment: Same as above. Indexes 6, 7, 8 included.

Comment: what is `journals[0]`?

Comment: Fixed. I attempted generalizing but left my actual code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
[match.start() for match in re.finditer(r"[^\s]+", words)]
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code:

```
words = "7 day f/u  with customer."
[match.start() for match in re.finditer(r"\b[a-zA-Z0-9](\/)?[a-zA-Z0-9]?", words)]
```

Output : `[0, 2, 6, 11, 16]`

Comment: While this gives the desired output my contrived example was not detailed enough. I was hoping for all non-alnums to be included in the word. I shall update the question.

Comment: What do you mean by `non-alnums`?

Comment: I want to include characters that are not letters or numbers that are adjacent or enclosed within a word to be counted as part of the word.

Comment: In that case using this regex `[^\s]+` would be useful.